# How to check if a value exists in a JSONB list

Tags: json, postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-11

I am trying to figure out in PostgreSQL 11 JSONB query

```
SELECT id, my_json_field #>> '{field_depth_1, field_depth_2}' 
FROM my_data 
WHERE my_json_field @> '{"other_field": 3}'::jsonb
```

If `other_field` is a key-value pair, this works perfectly and I get every row with `other_field = 3`. However, if `other_field` is a list of values, eg: [2,3,6,8,10], and I want to find out for every row whether the value 3 exists in the list represented by `other_field`, how should I write the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator `@>`. Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

> @>    jsonb   Does the left JSON value contain the right JSON path/value entries at the top level?

Example:

```
with my_data(id, my_json_field) as (
values
    (1, '{"field_depth_1": {"field_depth_2": "something 1"}, "other_field": 3}'::jsonb),
    (2, '{"field_depth_1": {"field_depth_2": "something 2"}, "other_field": 4}'),
    (3, '{"field_depth_1": {"field_depth_2": "something 3"}, "other_field": [2,3,6,8,10]}'),
    (4, '{"field_depth_1": {"field_depth_2": "something 4"}, "other_field": [2,4,6,8,10]}')
)

select id, my_json_field #>> '{field_depth_1, field_depth_2}' as value
from my_data 
where my_json_field->'other_field' @> '3'

 id |    value    
----+-------------
  1 | something 1
  3 | something 3
(2 rows)
```